# how to convert any forex pair quote to usd value?

Tags: python, forex

Is it possible to convert any forex pair quote to usd value?

I tried using following code but it gives incorrect results:

```
def calculate_instrument_value_in_account_currency(currency, current_prices, instruments):

    instrument_values = []

    #dictionary to keep prices for each currency, assuming that current_prices has prices in the same order as instruments list has instument names
    prices_for_currency = {}

    instrument_index = 0
    for instrument in instruments:
        prices_for_currency[instrument] = current_prices[instrument_index]
        instrument_index += 1

    #account currencu is USD
    if currency == 'USD':
        m = 0            
        for instrument in instruments:                                               
            first_currency = instrument[0:3]
            second_currency = instrument[4:7]

            #counter currency same as account currency
            if second_currency == 'USD':
                instrument_value = current_prices[m]
            #base currency same as account currency    
            elif first_currency == 'USD':
                instrument_value = 1 / current_prices[m]
            #none of the currency pair is the same as account currency
            #is needed the currency rate for the base currency/account currency
            else:
                if second_currency == 'JPY':
                    JPY_to_USD = prices_for_currency[currency+"/"+second_currency]
                    USD_to_JPY = 1 / JPY_to_USD
                    instrument_value = current_prices[m] * USD_to_JPY

                else: 
                    USD_to_GBP = prices_for_currency[second_currency+"/"+currency]
                    instrument_value =  current_prices[m] * USD_to_GBP

            instrument_values.append(instrument_value)
            m += 1    

    return instrument_values
```

Comment: What's a forex pair quote? Please provide a sample input.

Comment: first show what you have in variables - it is not obvious what data you use. You could use `print()` to see what you have in variables in different moments and compare it with calculations on paper. Maybe you should keep data in one list or dictionary instead of use separated `currency, current_prices, instruments` which may have elements in different order.

Answer (score -1):

That's basically a pathfinding problem: each currency is a node, each pair is a (directed) traversable link, and you're looking for the shortest path between each currency and your target. Since your "edge cost" is a constant 1 you can just use Dijkstra's algorithm to resolve it. Or just delegate that to a standard package like networkx.

Once you've defined your pathfinding graph, can create a map giving the path to your common currency from each other currency.

Comment: I am training a machine learning model for portfolio optimization. I want to convert the pairs value to one common currency.

Comment: To run the above function:

Comment: instruments = ['EUR/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/CAD', 'GBP/USD', 'NZD/USD', 'GBP/JPY', 'EUR/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'EUR/GBP', 'USD/CHF']
   
current_prices = [1.10270,109.27500,0.68263,1.31496,1.30712,0.66076,142.82700,120.46800,74.58800,0.84343,0.97120]

Comment: instrument_values_calculated = calculate_instrument_value_in_account_currency('USD', current_prices, instruments)

print(instruments)
print(current_prices)

print(instrument_values_calculated)

Comment: ['EUR/USD', 'USD/JPY', 'AUD/USD', 'USD/CAD', 'GBP/USD', 'NZD/USD', 'GBP/JPY', 'EUR/JPY', 'AUD/JPY', 'EUR/GBP', 'USD/CHF']
[1.1027, 109.275, 0.68263, 1.31496, 1.30712, 0.66076, 142.827, 120.468, 74.588, 0.84343, 0.9712]
[1.1027, 0.009151223976206817, 0.68263, 0.7604794062176797, 1.30712, 0.66076, 1.307041866849691, 1.102429649965683, 0.682571493937314, 1.1024642216, 1.0296540362438222]